# Where is the dependency information stored for an RPM package

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

With `yum deplist` one can check the dependencies of an RPM package. I am wondering where the information about the list of dependencies is stored. I downloaded the rpm package and checked its content with `rpm -qiap pkgname.rpm`, but it didn't contain dependencies. For example:

```
$ yum deplist nodejs010-2.1-5.sc1.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Finding dependencies: 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
package: nodejs010.x86_64 2.1-5.sc1.el6
  dependency: nodejs010-npm
   provider: nodejs010-npm.noarch 1.4.28-5.sc1.el6
   provider: nodejs010-npm.noarch 2.14.13-7.el6
  dependency: nodejs010-nodejs
   provider: nodejs010-nodejs.x86_64 0.10.40-1.el6
  dependency: nodejs010-runtime
   provider: nodejs010-runtime.x86_64 2.1-5.sc1.el6
   provider: nodejs010-runtime.x86_64 2.1-3.sc1.el6

$ rpm -qilp nodejs010-2.1-5.sc1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
 warning: nodejs010-2.1-5.sc1.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1   
 Signature, key ID f2ee9d55: NOKEY
Name        : nodejs010                    Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.1                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 5.sc1.el6                     Build Date: Fri 04 Nov 2016     03:44:19 AM CDT
Install Date: (not installed)               Build Host:   c1bd.rdu2.centos.org
Group       : Unspecified                   Source RPM:    nodejs010-2.1-5.sc1.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 0                                License: MIT
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Fri 23 Dec 2016 05:47:16 PM CST, Key ID 4eb84e71f2ee9d55
Packager    : CBS <cbs@centos.org>
Summary     : nodejs010 Software Collection
Description :
This is the main package for nodejs010 Software Collection.
(contains no files)
```

Looks like the dependency information is not directly stored in the RPM file. Then where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the RPM, but you need to use the `-R` option to see it:

```
rpm -qpR nodejs010-2.1-5.sc1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```